Make NAS discoverable to Network
Good evening,
I just got myself an Asustor NAS with a 10gbit ethernet port. On my PC (Windows 10) I have a PCIe 10gig ethernet card that I use to connect directly to the NAS. I my main ethernet port on my PC to connect to my network (router and other devices).
I want to now make the NAS available to other devices on the network and to my router so I can use the slower 1gig connection for all my devices but the fast 10gig connection for my computer where I edit videos. I do not want to shell out another 300 bucks for a 10gig ethernet switch and also cannot use routing tables in my router as it doesn't support them.
So according to my circumstances, I have looked into the following methods:
Network Bridging:
When I bridge my two ethernet ports via the "Network Connections" application on windows, I can access my NAS from all local devices, which is great. But the upload speeds are really slow. I read online that you must disable Large Send Offload for faster speeds and turning this off in the network adapters does make my upload speed to the internet back to what it should be, but pulling from my NAS is stuck at around 1.5gbps. I can send data to the NAS at almost the full 10gbit but pulling data from it caps out at way slower speeds. This is a huge issue for video editing.
A second problem is that I can then not port forward to my NAS anymore via my router, as the NAS is recognized to have the IP 0.0.0.0. As I want to access my NAS from work, a workaround for this is also needed.
Internet Connection Sharing (ICS):
This seems to not work as my NAS can then only access the internet but other devices on the network cannot access it. Am I mistaken here or is this really not a viable option?
Can anybody point me towards what I might be doing wrong with the Network Bridge or if there are other ways of doing this? Thanks so much!!

Do you want to make the NAS discoverable or only accesible? There are ways to make it accessible (by IP address) in this setup, but making it discoverable (via "Network devices") is going to be harder.

I want to connect to it via network drive on my directly connected pc and a macbook, also accessible from outside via the router
